# Capture registry changes between two snapshots and save the changes to a reg file

Tags: windows-registry

I am wanting to snapshot my registry once, install software then snapshot the registry again how-ever I then want to be able to compare the changes and save the added keys etc to a .reg file so I can write those changes to another machine. How would I go by doing this?

Comment: what error you face that requiere you to do that on a server ?

Comment: Ehm notte Export and diff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that I have not ever actually done this but other techs swear by this utility:

[Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) Is a Microsoft (SysInternals) utility that can capture changes to the registry and save them to a file.

Comment: Thanks for this! I managed to find a script that can convert the xml output from procmon to what I need :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the utility [Regshot](https://sourceforge.net/projects/regshot/) for this.

It is very self explanatory. Run the utility once and capture the "before" state. Make your changes and then capture an "after" state. The program itself can compare the differences and output a text file.

Note that some parts of the registry are live, dynamic data that does change whilst Windows is running. Therefore you may need to compare a few runs to see what is normal background activity and what related to the program of interest.